# React.js page does not switch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to control the page using react-hook, react-router-dom, redux.
The login screen is implemented and the code that tries to switch to the main page when the login is successful is written.

So I used history.push of react-router.
However, history.push only changes the browser url, not the actual information displayed on the page.
The code is shown below.

In brief code explanation,
The id and password are put into redux and get as getelementbyuId and sent as form data.
The login function works normally.
history.push ('/') written to "userUpdateUserInfo" doesn't work at all.
Only the url of the browser changes, not the main page.

### **App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Main, Login } from './pages';

import './css/App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App-contents-area">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/main" component={Main} />
          {/* <Redirect path="*" to="/" /> */}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### **LoginPage.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Login } from 'Component';

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <Login />
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

### **Login.tsx** (components)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  LoginTitle, LoginAvatar, LoginUserId, LoginUserPassword, LoginButton
} from '..';

import '../../css/Login.css';

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <div className="Login-form-data">
        <LoginTitle /> // code skip
        <LoginAvatar /> // code skip
        <LoginUserId /> // code skip
        <LoginUserPassword /> // code skip
        <LoginButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

### **LoginButton.tsx** (components)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useUpdateUserInfo } from 'Hook';

function LoginButton() {
  const { handleLogin } = useUpdateUserInfo(); // custom hook

  return (
    <div className="LoginButton">
      <button className="LoginButton-button" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginButton;
```

### **userUpdateUserInfo.tsx** (custom hook)

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from 'Store/modules';
import { updateUserInfo } from 'Store/modules/user';
import { userLoginStatus } from 'Store/modules/login';

import { msg } from 'Lang';
import {
  axiosPost, history, 
  _ShowFail, _ShowSuccess, _ShowSelect
} from 'Module';

export default function useUpdateUserInfo () {
  const { id, name, tel, email } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
  let { isLogin } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.login);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const handleLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const userId: string = (document.getElementById('LoginUserId-id') as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
      const userPw: string = (document.getElementById('LoginUserPassword-password') as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();

      if (!userId.length) { return _ShowFail(msg.pleaseInputUserId); }
      if (!userPw.length) { return _ShowFail(msg.pleaseInputUserPassword); }

      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('userId', userId);
      formData.append('userPw', userPw);

      const url = '/login/check-login-info';
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      };

      const res = await axiosPost(url, formData, config);

      if (res.data.res) {
        _ShowSuccess('login success');
        const userInfo = {
          id: res.data.rows[0].id,
          name: res.data.rows[0].name,
          email: res.data.rows[0].email,
          tel: res.data.rows[0].tel,
        };

        isLogin = true;
       /**************************/
        history.push('/main');    // now working
       /**************************/
        dispatch(updateUserInfo(userInfo));
        dispatch(userLoginStatus({ isLogin }));
      }
      else {
        _ShowFail('login fail');

        isLogin = false;

        dispatch(updateUserInfo({ id, email, name, tel }));
        dispatch(userLoginStatus({ isLogin }));
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      _ShowFail(error.message);
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return { handleLogin };
};
```

### **MainPage.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

function MainPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>MainPage!!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

### **history.tsx**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Since last night, I have been suffering from this problem.
How can I change the content of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.js your Routes suppose to be inside < Router > < /Router >,

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

(unless you wrap it on index.js that not including here and App is imported inside there)?

Comment: Thanks! As you say, adding history to your Router works!